# Lambda Distinct Select

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have this lambda and would like it to return Distinct list.

```
var ResourceTypeNameList = Resources.Select(r => new bl_SelectBox{ text=r.ResourceTypeName, value=r.resourceTypeID }).Distinct();
```

Am I missing something or should that return a distinct list?

Comment: It should but according to equality comparison for bl_SelectBox (if it's a custom reference type without anything else than its properties...each reference isn't equal to anything else).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti The current resources list has text = "Car", value = 1 X 2. However it returns them twice and It should return only once.

Comment: Is there something that you want to be distinct from each object? like text or value? In your case, it will return distinct references.

Comment: Does `bl_SelectBox` override `GetHashCode` and `Equals`? If not, try to implement this, or give an additional parameter to `Distinct` implementing `IEqualityComparer<bl_SelectBox>`

Comment: Complementing Caramiriel's comment - if not, `Distinct` might not filter anything as the input is a sequence of distinct objects.

Comment: It must distinct on value=r.resourceTypeID but i need to select text=r.ResourceTypeName.

Comment: @RudolphOpperman itself Distinct() doesn't know how to detect equality. That's why your object has to override GetHashCode and Equals or you specify a custom IEualityComparer as parameter.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you don't override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in your class or provide a custom equality comparer `Distinct` method uses default equality comparer for the type.And it compares reference types by references. Not by the property values. If you don't want this behaviour either override the relevant methods in your class or if you can't change the class implement an [`IEqualityComparer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the type and pass it to `Distinct`:

```
var ResourceTypeNameList = Resources
   .Select(r => new bl_SelectBox{ text=r.ResourceTypeName, value=r.resourceTypeID })
   .Distinct(new MyEqualityComparer());
```

Another quick solution would be using `GroupBy`:

```
var ResourceTypeNameList = Resources
  .Select(r => new bl_SelectBox{ text=r.ResourceTypeName, value=r.resourceTypeID })
  .GroupBy(x => x.SomeProperty)
  .Select(x => x.First());
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I went with the group by seeing as it is the most simple between then.